# NSUserDefaults changing every segue

Tags: swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

Sorry for the newbie question but i am really stuck.

I have a UIViewController and 4 tableviews in an app. When i click on a button on the UIViewcontroller it segues to a UITableviewController called "Beach". When the user clicks on a cell of the table, it segues back to the UIViewController and displays the selected cells title as the buttons title. The problem that i am having is when i click on a nother button to a tableview and then clicks on the cell, the previous buttons title sets back to the previous title.

i have a prepare for segue function in the tables view controllers and this returns the selected table title (named : Titleoftable) to the main VC which, the strings.

the way i am currently doing it is to make a NSUserDefault below but the problem still remains the same - The value changes top "" every time i click on another table V---

```
let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path!)

            let persistenceStoreKey = "MyStringKey"
            let stringToStore = "\((cell?.textLabel?.text!)!)"

            // Store data
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(stringToStore, forKey: persistenceStoreKey)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

            // Get data
            let myStringt = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(persistenceStoreKey)


            destination.textOfBeach = (myStringt)!
            destination.isBeachSelected = true


    }
```

I have been stuck on this problem for ages now! PLEASE HELP!!

PS- I am using swift-2 and Xcode7

Comment: It makes no sense to store something in NSUserDefaults and then immediately retrieve it. NSUserDefaults plays no role whatever in your logic. You might as well just say `let myStringt = stringToStore`

Comment: Can you review your question and fix the typos so your question is clearer? Also, I don't understand what you mean by, "the previous buttons title sets back to the previous title."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not pushing a new ViewController after you click on the tableview's cell. It gives me the impression that it might be the case since you are seeing only the title of the last cell you pressed.. Make sure you actually pop the tableview's controller instead of pushing a new one.

If you want to keep using NSUserDefaults, you could just call

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

in your cellSelection function, and read the defaults value in the viewWillAppear of the main ViewController.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standard()
    if let beachSelection = userDefault.string(forKey: "BeachControllerSelection") {
        textOfBeach = beachSelection
        isBeachSelected = true
    }
    //same for the rest of the other table view's selections
}
```

Comment: it is returning this error [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319160/value-type-error-swift-xcode?noredirect=1#comment67894354_40319160) @Antonio Anchondo

Comment: what view controller should i put the pop - the table or the main @Antonio Anchondo

Comment: popViewController is called on the UINavigationController  and pops the top most ViewController, so if you call it in main or table it will still pop the top most, it think it makes more sense to have the code in the table view as that's were the event triggering the pop is happening 
[link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller)

Comment: I think in your environment the function to pop is:

Comment: navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)