# Value type error SWIFT/XCODE

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift2, value-type

I have a table view where i want the view controller to pop instead of segue when the cell is selected although I am getting this error "Value of type 'UINavigationController' has no member 'popViewController'"-- Any ideas???[image: The image]

Please note: I am using swift 2 and xcode7

Comment: have you tried to restart rebuild, etc?

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in swift 2 and Xcode 7 the function is:

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```